# How do I avoid having to type -std=c++11 each time when compiling

Tags: c++, shell, c++11, ubuntu, cmake

**SOLUTION**: I used the solution by [Sander De Dycker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822669/sander-de-dycker) and just updated my gcc version, which worked perfectly.

First, I want to point out that I don't know anything about CMake or shell scripts.

**What** is the best way to avoid having to type `-std=c++11` each time when compiling a C++ file?

(e.g. g++ -std=c++11 file.c).

- I found a solution online, but it didn't seem to work or I didn't know how to use it properly:

  https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/issues/528

  > Put this line :
  >
  > set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
  >
  > after the first line of **CMakeLists.txt** located in src directory

  This `CMakeLists.txt` file didn't exist, so I just created it. This might've been a first mistake. Moreover, my assumption was that then I could just type `g++ file.c`, but maybe I have to type something else instead?
- My supervisor told me that the most efficient way was to use a **shell script**, which I am not familiar with. Any suggestions for this method?

Comment: If you don't have `CMakeLists.txt` files then you unlikely work with CMake. Then, why do you ask about CMake (and use `cmake`) tag, if you don't use CMake at all?

Comment: [gcc 6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html) changed the default to gnu++14 (ie. c++14 with extensions), so switching to a later gcc version will allow you to avoid adding that flag, as long as you are ok with also enabling the extensions (and a later C++ version than the one you actually want).

Comment: The best way is to use an IDE.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Because the first solution mentioned `CMakeLists.txt`, so it made sense to me to include the CMake tag.

@SanderDeDycker Thanks, I will have a look into this.

@MichaelChourdakis Any good suggestions for Ubuntu?

Comment: For single-source and small-projects, I agree with your supervisor. Just set a couple of variables with your commonly used options, e.g. `cflags="-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow"` and then `std="-std=c++11"` and then provide your filename to compile as an argument and call `g++ $cflags $std -o "${1%.*}" "$1"` to compile with the executable named the same as your `.cpp` file -- without `.cpp` (you can do neat tricks using `${@:2}` to add any other arguments to the end of your compile string)

Comment: @rlamesch I see development in linux quite futile, especially for a beginner. Visual Studio can create, run and debug a linux project directly from Windows.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I just upgraded to GCC/G++ version 6.5, which seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I use `alias c17=clang++ -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-padded -Wno-c99-compat -std=c++17` in my `~/.bash_profile` for quick compiles of single-file programs (such as found on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMakeLists.txt is the rule file build your project, gcc is one compiler.

1. create a CMakeLists.txt in your dir.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(project_name)
# use c++ 11
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD  11)
add_executable(func file.cpp)
```

2. create folder named `build`, and `cd build`
3. build it

```
cmake ..
make
```

4. finaly, you'll get execute file named `func`.

you should learn about CMake or Make
https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

An even simpler option is stick your defaults in a `Makefile`:

```
CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow
```

Then you can just call `make file` and Make will compile `file.cpp` into an executable `file` for you.